# moving file (external sdcard)

Tags: java, android, file

I try to move a file from one folder to the other as follow:

```
File fileFrom = new File("/storage/1AF5-2B0F/test/testfile");
File fileTo = new File("/storage/1AF5-2B0F/test2/testfile");
boolean moveok = fileFrom.renameTo(fileTo);
```

moveok is false

When doing the same with the internal sdcard it works. How can I move a file on the external sdcard ?

I have write permissions

```
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Are you sure `test2` directory exists?

Comment: Yes it exists. 100%.

Comment: Whats wrong with this question. Please comment why downvoting if you dare :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get to the root of `external storage` `(SD)`

```
 File from = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"1AF5-2B0F/test/testfile.jpg");
    File to = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/1AF5-2B0F/test2/testfile.jpg");
boolean moveok = from.renameTo(to);
```

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the external SD card directory.

```
File from = new File(/storage/1AF5-2B0F/test/testfile");
// You can use the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to get to the root of external storage (which, on some devices, is an SD card).
File to = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/test/testfile"); 
from.renameTo(to);
```